# Laravel Error: Failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have installed Laravel 5.8 using composer without any problems and every thing was working fine. But today when I try to execute "php artisan" in my terminal I have this typical error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqtU8.png)

Comment: Try `composer update` and after that `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Try `composer update` if don't work then delete vendor and reinstalled composer.

Answer (score -1):

I know you meet the question. You upgrade laravel5.8 And you don't run command compoer update